# Code crashes when splitting the tokens using strtok by passing the string to function

Tags: c

My code crashes when I try to split the tokens using `strtok` by passing the string to function. Here is my code:

```
    #define MAX_STRING_SIZE 256

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void getTokens(char *s1 ,char *ct1  ,char ***pppcToks ,int *nTkns)
{
    char *s2 = NULL;
    char *cp = NULL;

    cp = strtok(s1, ct1);
    (*nTkns)++;

    *pppcToks = (char **) malloc(1 * sizeof(char *));
    (*pppcToks)[0] = (char *)malloc(MAX_STRING_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    (*pppcToks)[0] = cp;

    while (NULL != (cp = strtok(NULL, ct1)))
    {

        *pppcToks = (char **)realloc((void *)(*pppcToks), (*nTkns) * sizeof(char *));
        (*pppcToks)[(*nTkns)] = (char *)malloc(MAX_STRING_SIZE * sizeof(char));
        (*pppcToks)[(*nTkns)] = cp;
        printf("%s\n", (*pppcToks)[(*nTkns)]);
        (*nTkns)++;
    }
    printf("%d", *nTkns);

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char ac[MAX_STRING_SIZE] = "Strtok#should#be tested to an extent";
    int nTkns = 0,inx;

    char **ppcList = NULL;


    getTokens(ac, "#", &ppcList, &nTkns);

    for (inx =0; inx < nTkns; inx++)
    {
    printf("%s", ppcList[inx]); //Fails in second loop
    }
    for(;;);

}
```

The first token gets printed. Crash occurs while printing further. Also note that I am using C++ compiler to compile C code, as I don't have one for C as such.

Comment: You allocate space for `(*pppcToks)[(*nTkns)]` but never copy anything into it. Also, all that indirection is a mess. Consider creating a `struct` and passing that to the function.

Comment: This would be an excellent time to start using debugger. It's easier to figure out what is going on when you can observe variables while stepping through the code.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp *Consider creating a `struct` and passing that to the function.*  Or actually *return* the value instead of trying to pass a pointer to something.

Comment: Just use `strdup(cp);` instead of `(char *)malloc(MAX_STRING_SIZE * sizeof(char));` (2 times!), that should make it work

Comment: I dont want to return any thing from the function. I just want  to play with the address in the stack and heap of memory

Comment: @Ctx, `strdup` is not C, unfortunately, but POSIX.

Comment: You cannot compile C code with a C++ compiler! They are different languages and have different semantics for a lot of identical syntax. Use a C compiler! One thing is the same: being a three-star programmer is not a compliment.

Comment: I dont have a c compiler. I am casting the void pointer to corresponding datatype pointers to make it work

Comment: @jeja Get one! gcc and clang are FOSS. The casts are not the only issues. Learn the language, this seems to be over your head right now.

Comment: Well, it's not as bad as some people might try to convey here, the main problem is, that you do not actually copy the string into the place you malloc'd, hence my suggestion to replace it by strdup(). You can of course also strcpy it after malloc'ing, which is quite the same.

Comment: It is printing successfully in get Token function. But while while printing in main it i saying cannot read the memory

Comment: fix like [this](https://ideone.com/wRdTT4)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It works!!Thanks  a lot!!But I have modified one line of code which actually worked!!moved (*nTkns)++; in while loop to start of the loop and it worked!!will post the answer

Answer (score 0):

Please find the working code:

```
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 256

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void getTokens(char *s1 ,char *ct1  ,char ***pppcToks ,int *nTkns)
{
    char *cp = NULL;

     /* get the first token */
    cp = strtok(s1, ct1);
    (*nTkns)++;

    (*pppcToks) = (char **) malloc(1 * sizeof(char *));
    (*pppcToks)[0] = (char *)malloc((strlen(cp) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy((*pppcToks)[0], cp);

    /* walk through other tokens */
    while (NULL != (cp = strtok(NULL, ct1)))
    {
        (*nTkns)++;
        (*pppcToks) = (char **)realloc((void *)(*pppcToks), (*nTkns) * sizeof(char *));
        (*pppcToks)[*nTkns-1] = (char *)malloc((strlen(cp) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy((*pppcToks)[*nTkns-1], cp);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char ac[MAX_STRING_SIZE] = "Strtok#should#be tested to an extent";
    int nTkns = 0,i;

    char **ppcList = NULL;


    getTokens(ac, "#", &ppcList, &nTkns);

    for (i =0; i < nTkns; i++)
    {
    printf("%s\n", ppcList[i]); 
    }
    for(;;);

}
```

Thanks all for your valuable suggestion!!

Comment: It's still not right. You allocate space to copy the string with `malloc` but then you re-assign the pointer with `(*pppcToks)[0] = cp`. With that, you've lost the mem returned by `malloc` (mem leak). Instead, you need to use `strcpy((*pppcToks)[0], cp)`.

Comment: @Johnny Mopp Thanks for the comment,Done that!!